# How do I change the L2CAP MTU on Windows CE 6.0R3?

Tags: bluetooth, windows-ce

I'm trying and failing to change the MTU for Bluetooth RFCOMM links to a Windows CE device.  The documentation states that I can use setsockopt() with the SO_BTH_SET_MTU option to change the MTU for either a listening or non-connection socket.

The issue is that if I set the client/server socket MTU to 1024 (on 2 separate devices, of course), the MTU is always negotiated back to the default of 672!  If I set the Minimum MTU on the listening socket to 1024, the client fails to connect, which leads me to believe that client sockets are ignoring the MTU configuration.

Does anybody have experience with altering the default MTU on Windows CE 6.0R3 devices?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand if you are changing MTU on 2 devices that you control (server and client) or if the client device is a third-party one.
In the second case it may be that it can't handle the minimum MTU you configured and this explains why it can't connect.

Comment: I'm simply trying to optimize communication between 2 of our devices.  The devices are exactly the same, although I can also use a PC as one of the devices for testing.  Windows CE supports the SO_BTH_SET_MTU sockopt, and it appears to work fine until the connection negotiation.

Comment: If you can test with a PC this may be useful to understand if the issue is on the listening side or on the connecting one (or both!). Use the PC as "server" or as "client" and check if it works.

Comment: It doesn't work with any combination of PC<->device or device<->device.  The MTU always reverts back to 672 bytes.  I assumed that on WINCE, everything for this part of the stack is done in the kernel, but maybe it is a limitation of the bluetooth chip itself.

Comment: What kind of bluetooth chip are you using? You may try to use a BTUSB-based USB dongle and check if you hit the same problem.

Comment: It's an Infineon PBA 31308 on an embedded device.  There is no way to connect a USB device to our microprocessor.